# ejs How do I get if-then-else behavior in scriptlet

Tags: node.js, if-statement, ejs, scriptlet

In generating HTML with node.js EJS I'm not able to use an "else if" 
if my scriptlet tags look like:

```
 <% var qtype; %>
 <% if (qobj.ansType == 1) { %>
 <% qtype = 'multiChoice'; %>
 <% } %>
 <% else if (qobj.ansType == 0) { %>
 <% qtype = 'shortAnswer'; %>
 <% } %>
 <% else { %>
 <% qtype = 'longAnswer'; %>
 <% } %>

 Type:<%- select_tag("type",
    [{"value": 'multiChoice',"text": "Multiple Choice"},
    {"value": 'shortAnswer',"text": "Short Answer"},
    {"value": "longAnswer","text": "Text Answer"}],
    {"value": qtype}) %>   //  qtype should be set based on if-else statements above
```

I get: `Unexpected else token in question.ejs while compiling ejs`

I'm trying to get the default item in the select pulldown to be conditional based on the value of qobj.ansType.   It should be set to multiChoice if qobj.ansType = 1 and shortAnswer if qobj.ansType = 0 .

Doc for EJS says I can use full javascript in scriptlets but it looks like 
else if isn't allowed so is it full javascript or not?  I'd prefer not doing 3 ifs in a row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the `else` statements immediately after the closing braces of an `if` statement. You can't have `else` or `else if` on its own line by itself.

Try:

```
 <% var qtype; %>
 <% if (qobj.ansType == 1) { %>
 <% qtype = 'multiChoice'; %>
 <% } else if (qobj.ansType == 0) { %>
 <% qtype = 'shortAnswer'; %>
 <% } else { %>
 <% qtype = 'longAnswer'; %>
 <% } %>
```

Comment: Thanks.  I accidentally discovered that myself.   The scriptlet stuff seems poorly documented.